# Remove A Node From XML File (DOM4J, JAVA)

Tags: java, dom4j

Since all other questions related to this topic refer to a specific programming problem (e.g. *'I get a NullPointerException when I try this and that'*) and the answers are fixing the programming errors, here is a simple solution to the following question:

**How can I delete a node from an XML file using DOM4J?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you already have the node you want to delete:

```
  Document document = node.getDocument();

  node.detach();

  XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter(document.getPath() + document.getName()), OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
  writer.write(document);
  writer.close();
```

The try-catch statement is omitted.

Short explanation:

1. Getting the document and storing it in a local variable is needed,
   because after detaching the node, you cannot get the document by
   calling node.getDocument()
2. calling ***detach()*** on the node will remove the node from the document object (not from the file)
3. creating an XMLWriter with ***OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint()*** is needed, if you don't want any blank lines in your document afterwards

For a more complete example, here is a JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void dom4j() throws DocumentException, IOException {
  String absolutePath = Paths.get(PATH_TO_XML).toAbsolutePath().toString();

  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  Document document = reader.read(absolutePath);
  Node node = document.selectSingleNode(XPATH_TO_NODE);

  node.detach();

  XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter(absolutePath), OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
  writer.write(document);
  writer.close();
}
```

For more information regarding DOM4J refer to:
http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html

And more information for XPath syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

To remove a node with XPath, this is how you can do in [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;

public class removeElement {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException,IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/ClOrdIDS/ClOrdID[@id='3']");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.remove();
        }
        xm.output("output.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: As much as I appreciate new solutions: this is not an answer to the question. This is an answer for the question **How can I delete a node from an XML file using XPath and vtd-xml?** or the title **Remove A Node From XML File (XPATH, VTD-XML, JAVA)**